# How do I allow a user to be able to type in an HTML text box that also has fixed drop down options like a select input element?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, select, textbox

Basically I want the functionality of both a drop down select and a textbox in the same form element. Is there a simple way to implement something like this? Would I have to create both the elements and just hide/show them depending on user clicks?

The time selection dropdown/textbox in Microsofts Outlook calendar is a perfect example of what I want. I don't think jQuery autocomplete would help in this situation.

A jQuery answer would be best!

Thanks

Comment: why do you think that jquery ui autocomplete wont help?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox Not practical to roll your own. I'm sure of the 10 or so examples they have on the site you can use the api to get exactly what you want or pretty darn close

Comment: yea thanks cleary i didnt look closely enough, this should work perfect, thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, this can be accomplished pretty easily without the overhead of jQUI. Here's a jsFiddle with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/c9wtV/